# How i can CATCH any error (network and graphql), and prevent promise.reject()?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

[image]

i Already can get Apollo Client errors:

```js
import {onError} from 'apollo-link-error'

function createLink() {
  return ApolloLink.from([
    createErrorLink(),
    createHttpLink(),
  ])
}

function createErrorLink() {
  return onError(function ({graphQLErrors, networkError}) {

    if (graphQLErrors) {
      graphQLErrors.map(({message}) => {
        console.log(`[GraphQL error]`, message)
      })
    }

    if (networkError) {
      console.log(`[Network error]`, networkError)
    }
    
  })
}
```

Yes, error handlers works, but how i can PREVENT promise rejection?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const errorLink = onError(({networkError, graphQLErrors, response}) => {

  // DO ANYTHING

  // Stop error propagation to next Links
  response.errors = null
})
```

HttpLink not see errors end not reject promise =)